# LWJGL Rotation: Won't rotate

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, rotation, lwjgl

I'm trying to rotate a object I've made with openGL and LWJGL. My problem is that it does not rotate at all. Here is the code I'm using to draw the object with:

```
public static void draw() {
    if (active) {
        tex.bind();

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glPushMatrix();
            glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, 1);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2f(x - (WIDTH / 2), y);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2f(x - (WIDTH / 2) + WIDTH, y);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex2f(x - (WIDTH / 2) + WIDTH, y + HEIGHT);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2f(x - (WIDTH / 2), y + HEIGHT);
        glPopMatrix();
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks right. You're sure `rotation` is in degrees (not radians) and is large enough to cause a noticeable rotation?

Comment: It was not, now it is and i still got no rotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, 1);
```

You *cannot* call any matrix functions between `glBegin` and `glEnd`. Move them to in front of the `glBegin` call.

Comment: Now i got a rotation, but the point that im rotation around is far off what i want... But thx! :D